# To create a series, is my understanding correct that it must have index and how to convert a selected row in data frame to a list

Tags: python, series

**This edited section below is for my previous question 1 and 2 if Series can do without index**
For series in puython, I want to seek clarification that when creating a Series, the values must be linked to an Index? See many examples, most of them have index when creating a series.

for example, using the code below, to create a series, values 1,2,3,4,5 must link to an index a,b,c,d,e. The numbers 1,2,3 etc cannot exist as values and index?

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],index = ['a','b','c','d','e'])

**Q3: How do I use data frame [Ticket] row and convert to a list?**
`count_list = loaddf["Ticket"].tolist()`

Tried converting the Ticket row to list but my code encountered errors. Below is the dataframe
[image]

Below is the error

```
count_list = loaddf["Ticket"].tolist() 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-410e0262e58c>", line 1, in <module>
    count_list = loaddf["Ticket"].tolist()

  File "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Ticket'
```

Comment: The index isn’t a column like the others, I’m confused. Why do you want to do all this? In “Q3” you mention that your code “encountered errors”. Can you be more specific? Can you also share enough of your code/anything else to create a [mcve].

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. Actually I just started python. So now writing some short scripts to understand. My first question is trying to get the values for Ticket rows (from data frame). Since it become a Series, trying to see if I can remove the index. As for the 3rd question, I edited my post with error message. Also posted a screenshot of the dataframe

Comment: “The numbers 1,2,3 etc cannot exist as values and index?” What do you mean by this? You removed Q1 and Q3 entirely, do you no longer want those to be answered?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**

You can’t!

**Q2**

See Q1.

**Q3**

You can access the row whose value in the `Revenue` column is `Ticket` like so:

```py
df.loc[df[‘Revenue’] == ‘Ticket’]
```

**I *strongly* recommend reading the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) in order to learn these basic notions.**

Let me know if you have another question or something is unclear :)

Comment: Thanks Alexander. It's for question 3. If I would want to get the Ticket row values as dictionary, can you guide what is the code to retrieve from DF? Dictionary in this way. {'Jan 2019':100, 'Feb 2019': 200, 'Mar 2019': 300

Comment: @vitalstrike82 I’m not sure, but try calling `.to_dict()` on the Series. If I were you I’d change the layout of that DataFrame. I think it would make more sense to have the dates as the index, especially since data types are by column.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1:

```
 df.reset_index(drop=True).set_index('0')
```

May work as it seems that column is named('0')

Comment: Thanks. This error appears. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: @vitalstrike82 `set_index()` is a method on DataFrames.